# How do I define 2 artifact with different when condition in 1 Job?

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I tried to make CI that build the code using gradle. The thing is, when the build failed, it didn't upload my test report, which what I need for debugging later.

```
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./gradlew build --info
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build/install/<app_name>/*
      - build/reports/*
    expire_in: 7 days
    reports:
      junit: build/test-results/test/TEST-*.xml
```

As gitlab-ci default, it only upload the artifact when build is success. But I need the test report to be always uploaded and the build file uploaded only when the build is success. I can use always and on_success but I'm not sure whether I can separate those 2 artifact when condition in 1 job.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a **stage** for gathering reports when an failure occurs.
In following example I added **build-reports** stage with `when: on_failure` and it is responsible for gathering logs and reports.

```
stages:
  - build
  - build-reports


build:
  stage: build
  allow_failure: false
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - report.txt
    - output.txt
    expire_in: 1 week
  script:
    - echo "Reports:" $(date) > report.txt
    - echo "Output:" $(date) > output.txt

Build-Reports:
  stage: build-reports
  when: on_failure
  artifacts:
    name: Build reports
    paths:
    - report.txt
    expire_in: 1 week
  script:
    - echo "Build Failed" >> report.txt
```

**Pipeline output for success build:** (**Build** stage's artifact contains: `report.txt` and `output.txt`)
[image: Pipeline output for success build]

**Pipeline output for failed build** (**Build-Reports** stage's artifact contains: `report.txt`)
[image: Pipeline output for failed build]